# Parenthesis in j-prolog editor

Tags: editor, prolog

I´m having some problems with parenthesis in the j-prolog editor, when I try to put () or [] the editor only recognizes de right symbol, the left symbol the editor put something like this ' or |. I´m using a macbook...

Answer (score 0):

Why bother ? It's old and not open source (for what I can see).

Among latest SWI-Prolog developments, swipl-win defines an interface running native SWI-Prolog IDE, portable on Darwin, Windows, Linux. I'm working on a *new* IDE based on this.

If you are interested in Java, then try [PDT](http://sewiki.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/docs/v2.1/start). It's state-of-the-art in the field. Or see the [page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/IDE.html) dedicated to IDEs.

If you (like me) do prefer NetBeans to Eclipse, there is [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/netbeans_ide_7_0_prolog) one. Sorry, I never tried it.

Comment: Hi capellic, I´m not using j-prolog editor anymore, i´m using swi-prolog-editor. But thanks for the reply